# Why is LINQ table empty?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm using EntityFrameworks.  I create an object like this:

```
using var myEntity = new MyEntity())
{
    ClassA classa = (from t1 in myEntity.Table1s
                     where t1.EmpoyeeId == empId
                     select t1).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

I'd like to access a table that is available off of classa.  I try classa.TableB.  But TableB is empty.  Is there something else I should do to load TableB?

Comment: Are you loading eagerly or lazily? If eagerly: are you including the appropriate collections?

Comment: I'm only doing the above.  Nothing else is happening to load additional tables.  They are usually available but not in this case.

Comment: You say you're using EF. Can you show us the code from `ClassA`? Is the `Collection<TableB>` defined as virtual or not?

Comment: Use 'ClassA classa = myEntity.Table1s.FirstOrDefault(t1 => t1.EmpoyeeId == empId); '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell EntityFramework that you want to eager load the joined the table.

This is done by using the "Include" extension method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx